# What's the difference between "skip" and "skip over"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

"I don't think these exercises are important so we're gonna **skip** this part"

"I don't think these exercises are important so we're gonna **skip over** this part"

Is there any difference between these two sentences? Are they both grammatically sound?

Comment: *We'll skip **over / past** [the part we don't need]* with either preposition or none at all - they all mean exactly the same. OR *...skip **to** [the next part we're interested in]* (where the preposition is *necessary* for that sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a preposition you have to use the right one. For example, you might say to *jump over* an obstacle or *run past* it.

Likewise, you can skip *to* something, skip *past* it, skip *over* it etc. It just depends on what seems most appropriate to the context.

Comment: Gotcha. Would the sentence make sense without the preposition tho?

Comment: @Satya Yes. To simply 'skip' something usually means to miss it out.